# Помогите разобраться с Outlook API

Tags: api, outlook

Мне нужно реализовать чтение писем из outlook. Я не смог найти чёткого описания того какие запросы нужно отправлять, чтобы авторизоваться и читать входящие письма.
Вобщем сервис outlook развёрнут на сервере компании и имеет url: https://mail.x5.ru (доступ к нему только через vpn), но как я понял запрос на авторизацию нужно слать на login.microsoftonline.com, но как этот запрос должен выглядеть я так и не понял.
Подскажите как это можно сделать зная логин и пароль?